# How do I make AWS validate my cross-account subdomain certificate?

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, ssl-certificate, amazon-route53, cname

In AWS account X, I already have a hosted zone and a valid certificate for my domain, `mydomain.com`.
In AWS account Y, I would like to create a subdomain `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` and create a certificate for that subdomain.

In account Y I requested a certificate for `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` (also covering `*.mysubdomain.mydomain.com`). I created a hosted zone for `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` and added a CNAME record to that hosted zone based on the newly requested certificate.

Finally, in my original hosted zone in account X, I created an NS record for `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` and copied over the name servers from the hosted zone in account Y.

My certificate request is still pending validation. Is there a step I have missed which is needed to make AWS validate the certificate?

EDIT: additionally, when I do `nslookup -mysubdomain.mydomain.com`, I get `server can't find mysubdomain.mydomain.com: NXDOMAIN`. (nslookup works for the root domain.) That might help diagnose the issue?

Comment: You listed all the correct steps. Since you are delegating the sudbomain to another Route53 zone, it may take a while to propagate if you set all that up at the same time. You should try testing the DNS records via something like https://dnschecker.org/ to verify those CNAME records AWS is looking for are actually showing up on DNS queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, the answer is: yes the steps I listed are sufficient, I had just accidentally created the NS record in the wrong hosted zone.